# "The <scores are> <score is> tied at 3–3."

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, singular-vs-plural

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tie_1):
**(1)** *The scores are tied at 3–3*.
I don't understand why "scores" is used in plural here. What does it mean?

my variant:
**(2)** *The score is tied at 3–3*.
What is the difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: Manchester City play Spurs. MC's score is 3; Spurs' score is 3. Two scores, plural. You could say the result is tied at 3-3 (or 'is a draw').

Comment: In American English, a score is what mathematicians would call an ordered pair. It specifies both teams’ (or athletes’) status in a combination.  “3 to 3,” “5 to nothing,” and “15 love” are three scores. We don’t have a term for one component of a score, though I *guess* we might say in a situation where Baltimore is leading New York 3-0 that the Orioles’ score is 3… but it sounds odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, a Canadian, in events where individuals get scored alone, like ski jumping, or gymnastics, "score" refers to the points an individual earned. The individual score has meaning all by itself because it reflects the overall quality of the performance.

In events where there's opposing sides, like hockey, tennis or snooker, "score" refers to the ordered pair of each side's accumulated points. Talking about one side's score alone is just about meaningless, so to me, "The scores are tied" describes more than one game, and in each game, the score between the opponents is tied.

I understand that UK English allows for "the scores" to refer to both sides in one game, but since everyone here agrees that "the score" can be an ordered pair referring to both sides in one game, saying "the score" is probably the best choice when referring to a single game.

Answer (score 2):

As an American I've heard both. I think that both of the comments are correct with no difference between them.

A single team/player's score can be a score, and so the collection of both teams' scores is plural. Or, a game itself can have a score, which is an ordered pair and can be singular. They are both fine to use. Here are some uses in sentences:

- Did you watch the game last night? What was the final score?
- I like tracking scores from my favorite players.
- She's on the edge of her seat, the scores are tied and there's only 30 seconds left!

Comment: Really? “The **scores are** tied”? In American English? Fascinating. As my comment to the OP suggests, to *me* that sounds really weird.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum - In UK English "The scores are/were tied" is absolutely normal in soccer, rugby, cricket, speedway etc. Saying 'the score is/was tied' is not unknown though.

Comment: Yes, @MichaelHarvey, that’s why I specified *American*. FriendlyRacoon specifies that they too are American.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Yeah, I definitely wouldn't blink twice at that, but I'm also not involved in sports culture much? So my context comes from more casual use. I'm from the northeast, but my parents both grew up on the west coast, not sure if it's a regional thing? Dialectal differences are fascinating!

Comment: Now that I think about it, most of the context I have for discussing scores comes from more individual competition (e.g., music performance adjudication, ice skating, skiing, bicycle racing, that sort of thing), where a single competition has lots of competitors, each with their own score. In that context, it wouldn't make sense to use score to talk about the competition itself, because it would have too many parts. So while I've certainly heard people talk about more traditional "A vs B" sports, maybe my perspective is shifted.

Comment: @FriendlyRacoon, that makes sense.

Comment: I think maybe this isn't so much about whether Brits or Americans think of a single game having a single "score", or one score for each side. It's that Brits say [***it was a draw***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scores+were+tied%2Cscore+was+tied%2Cit+was+a+draw&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) where Americans say [***the score was tied***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scores+were+tied%2Cscore+was+tied%2Cit+was+a+draw&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3)